# Оплата через яндекс.кассу в приложении

Tags: android

Добрый день!
Скажите, кто-нибудь реализовывал в своих приложениях оплату через яндекс.кассу?  В описании api сказано, что можно воспользоваться [sdk для android](https://github.com/yandex-money/yandex-money-sdk-android).
Библиотеку я добавил, написал код для вызова активити платежа:

```
PaymentParams params = new P2pTransferParams.Builder("1234567812345678")
            .setAmount(new BigDecimal(1))
            .build();
    Intent intent = PaymentActivity.getBuilder(getBaseContext())
            .setPaymentParams(params)
            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setHost(HOST)
            .build();
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Но в активити выводится ошибка **Ничего не получится. Возможность платить с этой банковской карты в приложении заблокирована**. В логе видно, что приходит такой json-ответ **{"status":"refused","error":"illegal_param_client_id"}**. Приложение зарегистрировано в яндекс.деньги.
Если использую CLIENT_ID из примера с гитхаб, то все работает.
Подскажите, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Привет, у меня таже проблема, если вы нашли решение, пожалуйста дайте мне знать
whoose.daddy@gmail.com
skype: whoose.daddy

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в CLIENT_ID. Должно работать "из коробки", у вас же запрос отклоняется на сервере. Проверьте id, если есть возможность, получите другой id.
Если ничего не помогает, в тех. поддержку яндекса